# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Spatial' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-storage

I get this error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Spatial, Version=5.7.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=49ba329had364evz' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I tried to uninstall/update `System.Spatial` and `WindowsAzure.Storage` Nuget packages but still get the error.

It's a dependency of `WindowsAzure.Storage` package, but funny thing is that I don't get this error when running my ASP.NET Web API project locally, but only on the Azure server.

I don't know where to find the assembly's manifest, is it `packages.config`?

How to get rid of this error? I already wasted two days :(

Comment: Does your project has same version of .Net like this assembly?

Comment: You probably need to install the version that you get in the error. Choose the appropriate version from the Nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I don't know, Visual Studio wasn't uploading newer `.dll` file to the server.
So I manually uploaded `System.Spatial` version 5.7.0 on the server.

(although still I don't know how could I change the version in a so called manifest.)

Comment: That was crazy two days :_(

Comment: Have you tried to add a binding redirect in app.config/web.config? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 12):

Changed the version details in configuration file based on ***DLL version present in bin*** folder of project having issue.

In configuration file it was referring to **version 5.6.4** but I have changed to **version 5.6.3** which resolved the error.

Before Change

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

After change.

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.3.0" newVersion="5.6.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using visual studio, go to nugget package manager and view installed packages, and use update pane to update system.spatial package,

this solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

**Fit all dependencies to your current azure version by the following two steps:**

- open Package Manager Console window
- enter `PM> Install-Package    WindowsAzure.Storage -Version [your_version_number]-preview -Pre`

this is what solved the problem in my case.